# how to print variables and comment separately?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to display comments from variables file?

## Content of variables.conf

```
VAR1=/destination1                       # comment
VAR2=/destination2                       # comment
```

## Script

```
VAR1=./variables.conf

for file in $(cat $VAR1 | sed 's/^/$/');
do
echo "${file%=*}"
done
```

## Output

```
$VAR1
$VAR2
```

**I need output to be like that and cannot figured out**

```
$VAR1         # comment
$VAR2         # comment
```

Comment: Comments are discarded when shell is reading the line. So you cannot retrieve them. But if you have the source you may search for variable definition. But you are giving comment some semantic meaning, which it is against the principle of comments. What if a user will put comment on the line before the definition? If you want data, you must create an convention, e.g. VAR1_NOTE="something"

Comment: @RafalNiznik : You could define an associative array, where the keys are the variable names, and the comments are the variable values.  I don't see what good this would be for, but after all, the whole idea of storing comments in variables, is a bit pointless. You could use a programming language where you can stuff additional information into variables; Common LISP for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why people are overcomplicating this so badly. Simply loop line by line and extract the comment the way you extract the name:

```
VAR1=./variables.conf

sed 's/^/$/' "$VAR1" | while read -r file
do
echo "${file%=*}    #${file##*#}"
done
```

or just do it all with `sed` in the first place:

```
sed -e 's/^/$/; s/=[^#]*/    /' "$VAR1"
```

Comment: this is great point! 
also this works the way I need thanks for help.
There is only one more question 
How to adjust comments so they line up

Comment: You can align and format with `printf`: `printf '%-30s #%s\n' "${file%=*}"  "${file##*#}"`

Answer (score 0):

Comments are by definition invisible outside the script, they cannot be exported or used (well, kinda, but that's another story).

It would be possible to do what you mean by creating two string variables with the intended comments and later use an echo command to dislay them, something like :

```
#! /bin/bash

comment1="# Hey-ho"
comment2="# Let's go"

VAR1=/destination1
VAR2=/destination2

echo -e "$VAR1 $comment1\n$VAR2 $comment2"  #why waste a good echo ;)
```

This should do the job. You can BTW skip de '#' as waht will be shown is obviosuly a string, but just to keep your syntax. And of course, my last commend won't be printed.

Of course, you will have to duplicate work, but as I said, comments are comments and not meant to be shown unless you are reading the code.

Comment: in above example variables.conf  it is not #!/bin/bash file and if your run 
VAR1=./variables.conf

for file in $(cat $VAR1 | sed 's/^/$/');
do
echo "${file%=*}"
done

this displays all content that is present under variables.conf
adding comments as separate variable might work but his is additional work it is not needed 
I thing solution here might be here 
echo "${file%=*}"  +  (something to display comments )

Comment: You should use `echo -e`. Otherwise the `\n` isn't parsed. Also, this is quite a lot of programming and it is expected that the programmer maintains variables for every comment. I would rather suggest to declare a hashmap and store the corresponding value as `[VAR1]="comment`. This way you can make it more dynamically.

Comment: Hi, THX I always forget :)
But neat idea the one iwth the hasmap!
In any case I woas just trying to make it visible that it's a lot of work for (almost) nothing. Unless the OP has a good use case, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I've scripted a little function for you. I expect that the var isn't defined twice, otherwise you'll have to make sure that `grep` only gets the first. Also, this will not work on really old bash versions, I use version `5.0.3`.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

SCRIPTNAME=$0
VAR1=/destination1                       # comment 1
VAR2=/destination2                       # comment 2

function print_comment {
        local var_name=$1
        local -n var_content=$1
        local comment=""

        comment=$(grep -E "^${var_name}=.*" $SCRIPTNAME | sed -r 's/^[^#].*(#.*)$/\1/')
        echo "$var_content $comment"
}

print_comment VAR1
print_comment VAR2

exit 0
```

This outputs:

```
$ ./tst.sh 
/destination1 # comment 1
/destination2 # comment 2
```

Comment: The `-n` flag is since introduces in bash-4.3 according [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498280/target-system-bash-give-me-parameter-error-when-i-use-local-n-how-am-i-allow#answer-498281) answer.

Comment: thanks for help this might work but unfortunately I do not use postfix local command in that environment. Do you thing it might be done other way? 
Also I do not keep variables in that same script. I keep variables under different files where I pull them by VAR1=./variables.conf

Comment: Do you mean that `local` does not exist? Also, do you `source` those files?

Answer (score 0):

A way with mapping variable name as key and comment as value in a Bash 4+ associative array:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

varfile='variables.conf'

# shellcheck source=./variables.conf
. "$varfile"

# shellcheck disable=SC2155 # safe assignement
declare -A comments="($(
while IFS=$'\37' read -r k v; do
  printf '[%q]=%q\n' "$k" "$v"
done< <(sed 's/^\([^=]*\)=[^#]\+#\ \?\(.*\)/\1\x1F\2/' "$varfile")
))"

for varname in "${!comments[@]}"; do
  comment="${comments[$varname]}"
  value="${!varname}"
  printf '%-20s %-30s %s\n' "$varname" "$value" "$comment"
done
```